# How to disable .war redeploy when JBoss 7.2 restart?

Tags: java, jboss

I'm using JBoss 7.2 eap (WIN10) for a project. Whenever I restart the JBoss for some reason, it redeploys my .war file. This situation causes rewrite my conf. files. I searched for some resources and questions about this topic. So I change the "deployment scanner subsystem" config default to this from standalone.xml. But it still redeploys my .war file after the restart. How can I solve this?

**Auto Deploy Exploded**
*false*

**Auto Deploy Xml**
*true*

**Auto Deploy Zipped**
*false*

**Deployment Timeout**
*600*

**Path**
*deployments*

**Relative To**
*jboss.server.base.dir*

**Runtime Failure Causes Rollback**
*${jboss.deployment.scanner.rollback.on.failure:false}*

**Scan Enabled**
*true*

**Scan Interval**
*5000*

Comment: Are you storing these conf. files inside the exploded WAR file? Because if they need to be modifiable, that's a terrible practice. As you've seen, every redeploy can cause the current contents to be replaced. Try storing the config files outside of the WAR file, and refer to the location using a system property defined in JBoss that the application can read.

Comment: When you restart your jboss, you have to deploy the application if you want to run it. If you want to remove the application from jboss - just remove the war. There is no way to have the application without deploying it

Comment: The scanner can be set not to auto-deploy

Comment: @ehsavoie ty for the reply, I tried to Scan Enabled = false. But at that time it's not auto-starting the application. You have to reach the management console and start the app yourself.
I need a configuration that will not redeploy my .war file in cases where it is necessary to restart the server.

Comment: Note that if your application is not deployed it won't work. There is a deployment process that occurs when a deployment is found. This can be disable, however the server will effectively not have the deployment.